# htaccess redirect user to his profile

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a domain `www.domain.com` and I have users who create profiles on it with a username. I have created a mechanism for them to access their public profile as `www.domain.com/username` using htaccess and some code in index.php file.

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]
```

An additional feature is that users can select a design (1st or 2nd design) for their profile. So I store the chosen design in database and redirect `www.domain.com/username` to `www.domain.com/1/` or `www.domain.com/2/` and load the users profile on that URL. The logic for that in **PHP** is

```
//Load profile of user
$requestURI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$parameterArray = explode('/', $requestURI);
$username = $parameterArray[1];

if($username != "")
{
    //Get chosen design from database and store it in a variable
    $chosenDesign = *Selected design value*;
    header("Location: $chosenDesign/");
}
else
{
    //Username not found, hence redirect to error page
    header("Location: 404.html");
}
```

My problem is, how can I redirect in such a way that the URL is always `www.domain.com/username` and it loads the design in the background (logically) and displays it.

Comment: Which framework do you use?

Comment: I do not use any framework. I have coded the entire logic to display data from database.

Comment: So, you're basically trying to write your own router?

Comment: Yes. That's right. I have converted a bunch of HTML files to PHP files and I display data in those converted HTML files from the backend (MySQL)

Comment: I can't help you directly, but maybe good thing to do would be looking at existing routers in popular frameworks? For example Symfony2, Laravel or Cake.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to hide information in a visible link.
You can use a link like that:

`www.domain.com/username-1` redirect to -> `www.domain.com/page.php?user=username&design=1`

For that kind of stuff, I use cookies...

Comment: I think we can hide the link via htaccess. I was successful in achieving the above problem when I had just 1 design. I loaded the design by default. But I just don't seem to get the htaccess correct for 2 designs.

Comment: You can sometimes hide the transformation or change of a link. But you need to show or starting link or final link. And all relevant information must be included in one or the other. You can hide information in cookies...